# XPathSelectElements in a confusing XML file

Tags: c#, xml

This is silly but I am tapping out here guys...

I have this XML file, and I need to get the value of 2021 out of the following line: **<A:product-version>2021</A:product-version>**

And here is my full XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<entry xmlns:A="urn:schemas-autodesk-com:partatom" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

<title>REVIT_2021_PROJECT</title>

<updated>2022-07-06T09:56:13Z</updated>


-<A:taxonomy>

<term>adsk:revit</term>

<label>Autodesk Revit</label>

</A:taxonomy>


-<A:taxonomy>

<term>adsk:revit:grouping</term>

<label>Autodesk Revit Grouping</label>

</A:taxonomy>


-<link href="." type="application/rvt" rel="design-2d">


-<A:design-file>

<A:title>REVIT_2021_PROJECT.rvt</A:title>

<A:product>Revit</A:product>

<A:product-version>2021</A:product-version>

<A:updated>2022-07-06T09:56:13Z</A:updated>

</A:design-file>

</link>


-<A:features>


-<A:feature>

<A:title>Project Information</A:title>


-<A:group>

<A:title>Identity Data</A:title>

</A:group>


-<A:group>

<A:title>Energy Analysis</A:title>

</A:group>


-<A:group>

<A:title>Route Analysis</A:title>

</A:group>


-<A:group>

<A:title>Other</A:title>

<Project_Issue_Date type="system" typeOfParameter="Text" displayName="Project Issue Date">Issue Date</Project_Issue_Date>

<Project_Status type="system" typeOfParameter="Text" displayName="Project Status">Project Status</Project_Status>

<Client_Name type="system" typeOfParameter="Text" displayName="Client Name">Owner</Client_Name>

<Project_Address type="system" typeOfParameter="Multiline Text" displayName="Project Address">Enter address here</Project_Address>

<Project_Name type="system" typeOfParameter="Text" displayName="Project Name">Project Name</Project_Name>

<Project_Number type="system" typeOfParameter="Text" displayName="Project Number">Project Number</Project_Number>

</A:group>

</A:feature>

</A:features>

</entry>
```

And here is my c# code

```
        XDocument XprojectXMLfile = XDocument.Load(projectXMLfilePath);

        var nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        nsMgr.AddNamespace("A", "urn:schemas-autodesk-com:partatom");

        var revitVersion = XprojectXMLfile.XPathSelectElements("/A:entry/A:link/A:design-file/A:product-version", nsMgr);
```

I messed with the XPathSelectElements and namespaces but I have exhausted all my ideas and my brain is giving out :'C

Comment: You do not need namespace : doc.Descentants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "product-version").FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @jdweng `Descendant` is likely a lot less efficient than going by an exact path, it has to do a full recursive search

Comment: @Charlieface : Both have to search every tag.  The efficiency is the SAME. My is probably faster since it doesn't have to include the prefix.

Comment: @jdweng Not sure you're right about that, an XPath should be able to descend to exactly where it needs to be according to the path (admit it's hard to find the exact source code). But you could equally do `.Elements` all the way down, which would also be more efficient than `.Descendants`

Comment: @Charlieface : The tag is not a root level.   Descendants is easier to use since you do not need the FULL PATH.

Comment: @jdweng Removing `/` at the start means it doesn't go back to the root. Equally `.Elements` will only go downwards. I agree `.Descendants` is easier, doesn't make it the right thing to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem to be that the elements not prefixed with an `A:` such as `<link>` element is in the document's default namespace, the Atom namespace, not the autodesk namespace. XPath 1.0 has no notion of a non-empty default namespace, so you will need to add a prefix to the namespace manager for Atom as well:

`nsMgr.AddNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");`

and qualify the core Atom elements in the XPath:

`var revitVersion = XprojectXMLfile.XPathSelectElements("/atom:entry/atom:link/A:design-file/A:product-version", nsMgr);`

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much. The fact that Atom didn't have a prefix in the XML file threw me off, and I didn't realize I can just declare my own inside my application. I learns